# What is the basic knowledge before starting Japanese language lesson?

Tags: learning

I am trying to learn Japanese from the start. I live in Penang, Malaysia. We have the Penang Japanese Language Society (PJLS) here but before I join, I would expect some basic course or level that I can fit into. Also, what are the hierarchy of the levels for Japanese language learning?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear to me what you're asking, so I've put the question on hold for now.  This question was also flagged as off-topic by one of our users, and I think that may be the case as well; I'm afraid I don't see a specific question about the Japanese language here.

Comment: I believe there are some users who learnt Japanese language before and possible they could have hard time during the initial stage. This topic might serve to provide me guidance and advice in terms of proficiency in each degree of Japanese language course. Can I say that I am trying to prepare myself by seeking advice and suggestion here before starting the Japanese class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much depends on your enthusiasm. You can start taking courses for the Japanese Language Proficiency Tests (JLPT), which is a standard proof of knowledge in the language. It has an hierarchy of N5 to N1, with N5 being the most basic course.

Now you can ask your PJLS how they go about with their courses or you can buy book and/or self study with help of online resources. You can even choose to ignore the tests altogether and learn from books which are not targeted for JLPT. For example, I have heard Japanese from Zero is quite a good series to learn from (haven't read it myself).

Comment: I think your answer misunderstands what s/he wants to know which appears to be what sort of beginning course s/he can take in Japanese -- not how Japanese tests are organized that s/he could self-study for.

Comment: Put aside any test at the moment, I just want to know which level of program/studies/lessons should I take for a student with zero experience like me.

Comment: @TanSiongZhe Well I just gave the info about the test levels. Depends on you how to prepare for the test. I have no idea about the courses offered there for the tests. So, that is for you to find out.